# guard gem run all triggers on start

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

Hi this is driving me crazy. I couldn't find a solution after a long time.

How do I trigger a "run_all" for all guards in the Guardfile.

When i run "guard" in the shell, I want it to sort off pretend like all files have changed and trigger all guards.

What's a clean way to do this from the Guardfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens for me with no additional configuration. I've noticed that some guards have options to override this behavior. For instance, guard-rspec has the all_on_start option, which you can set to false if you don't want to run your specs when you fire up guard.

As specified in the guard readme, if you are using guard >= 0.7.0, you can press enter to call each guards #run_all method in the order they are listed in the Guardfile. Try that?

Answer (score 4):

Create a guardfile on the root of the app and set the guard config to something like rspec example:

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_on_start => false do
```

Comment: He's asking how to run all tests automatically, so shouldn't this be `:all_on_start => true` instead?